# SSL for Amazon Ec2

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2

I'm moving my hosting from justhost.com (horrible) to the amazon cloud as it's cheaper, faster, and far more flexible.

My conundrum is that I will need SSL installed in the Amazon cloud. Note - I already purchased an SSL cert from justhost.com (actually through geocerts.com) and have the private key, domain cert and trust cert in my hand.

Question is -> Do I need to buy a new cert for the Amazon instance, or can I reuse my current cert? (The answer seems to be a resounding yes)

I have 3 files all downloaded from geocerts.

1) domain.crt :the cert for the domain

2) private.key : my private key

3) issuer.crt : the issuer certificate

Below is my httpd.conf snippet

```
  NameVirtualHost *:443
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>
     ServerName www.casinobitco.in
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/domain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/issuer.crt
  </VirtualHost>
```

Now, in testing - the cert doesn't seem proper? It basically looks self-signed, fake, etc.
https://ec2-54-232-212-186.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Any pointers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse your current certificate. You need you private key file, certificate file, and if needed a certificate chain file. What you need to do to set it up depends on your web server. It should be relatively easy to set it up.

Comment: That's good to know, however let me update my question with more info and maybe you can point me in the right direction on why this isn't working.

Comment: @timw07 The question is complete and has been answered. You should mark the answer as accepted, then create a new question if you need to solve some problems with installing certs.  Note, however, that the question probably belongs on ServerFault.com not here.

Comment: It is highly appreciable if you anyone answer "How to install SSL certificate in AWS"

Comment: @AshokKS There are a lot of ways you could do that. It all depends what on how your infrastructure is set up.